# Query Parse Class and Group Results by Year on iOS

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a Parse class that contains a column that uses the `Date` data type, and I want to group the results by year in a `UITableView`.

My initial thought is that I could query all the records, pull out the year from the date, and then save an array of years.

I would then query Parse again using `lessThan` and `greaterThan` operators to compare each value in my year array (Jan 1, XXXX to Dec 31, XXX) with the `Date` column in Parse.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Should I be using subqueries somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get anything other than a flat array from the query.  The only reason to query all the records is if you need them all.  Otherwise, constrain your query however you would otherwise, sort by the date column you care about, and then do the grouping after the query.

One choice you might consider is to move the query to cloud code and do the grouping on the server.  One advantage of this approach is that you can use underscorejs on the server, which has a groupBy function out of the box...

```
// in your cloud code js
var _ = require('underscore');

Parse.Cloud.define("queryMyClass", function(request, response) {
    var query = Parse.Query("MyClass");
    query.ascending("dateColumn");
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        return _.groupBy(results, function(result) {
            return result.get("dateColumn").getYear().toString();
        });
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

This find promise will be resolved as:

```
{ "114": [pfobject, pfobject, ...],
{ "115": [pfobject, pfobject, ...] ... }
```

where 114 means 2014, 115 means 2015, and so on.  You can do the same in objective-c at the client, but js/underscore does the job with far less code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I hadn't previously thought of using Cloud Code for this (I'm new to Parse). I've successfully created a query and have parsed the data in Swift. I think this will make it a lot easier to construct the table I'm after.

Comment: Oh, and for what it's worth, I found that `getFullYear()` will return the actual year and seems to be a replacement for `getYear()`. Thanks again for your help!